# Path too long exception...ususally it's normal, occasionally a bunch of junk is inserted

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Asp.net MVC app,

Getting this error:

System.IO.PathTooLongException: The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.

Path usually to looks like this:

http://live.jobcorps.org/Home.mvc.aspx/Index

When the error happens it looks like this:

https://live.jobcorps.org/(F(j80ac5jO2I2xABtZuGvriVYFDgMP8yK591c6y9lX65rAvk5tU_VO-YX6SmSOSn3rgWwmfEpjCR5bD39u1Pds9oN3z_3cXBDbymUWbJhv6fRa55TQZHHrxzgDQZiGkxTDtogeYrNnbz1he1g4zH_XhDHGk8us_Hnl6r5WgOPvJWUg_KJU6eGiu6g-Mp5fuuriWuvbBw2))/Home.mvc.aspx/Index

My theory is that there are certain servers/client that are configured differently and have this extra stuff in the path.

Can anyone tell what causes the junk in the url (session?) and how to prevent it?

Comment: Does anybody know what causes the path to get so long? Are the cookies turned off on thier browser or something?

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Answer (score 2):

I think http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/MS10-070 this security patch have  produce side effects.

Check your UrlSegmentMaxLength value in registry.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/820129

Comment: Both good answers gave both an upvote, will give the checkmark to whichever we implement. Thanks!

Comment: I was getting the above exception caused by the 51 degrees framework, which resulted in shutting down the app pool and 500 errors for all users! it was caching its optimised images in massively long path names. setting the HTTPRuntime web config value didn't help, but adding the UrlSegmentMaxLength registry key sorted me out. thanks @takepara

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try adding an option to your Web.config:

```
<httpRuntime maxUrlLength="1000" relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />
```